# How to make optional parameters mandatory

Tags: java

I need the originId and description fields to be optional if the status is 'CREATED' and mandatory if it's 'UPDATED'.

```
@PutMapping("{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public Mono<Void> update(@PathVariable (value = "id") String id,
                     @RequestBody @Valid PackageDTO request) {
        return update.execute(id, request);
}

public class PackageDTO {
    private Long originId;
    private String description;
    private PackageStatus status;
}

public enum PackageStatus {
    CREATED, UPDATED;
}
```

I tried to use 'required' in Requestbody but i did not succeed

Comment: What about checking inside the receiving function using a simple if/switch? if(UPDATED && (originId == null || description == null))

Comment: Yea.  Annotations don't allow you to express *conditionality*.

Comment: You can try to write a custom validator https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator